# Idiom "Catches Me Out"

Tags: idioms, north-american-english

According to [MW "catch me out"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catch%20out) means:

> caught out; catching out; catches out
>
> *transitive verb*
> 1
> : to detect in error or wrongdoing
>
> > caught him out committing perjury
>
> 2
> : to take unawares or by surprise

As a native speaker in Chicagoland, I've never heard this. Where is this sort of idiom common? I heard it originally from someone who might be Brit. Is this used in other parts of the US? Across the pond? Down under or among Kiwis? Canucks? Is it used in the Midwest and I just haven't heard it? Anyone know of any resources that would confirm that this is common US vernacular and not just a dialect some dictionary writer decided to include out of his fondness of the King's English?

**I'm looking for evidence or citations that characterizes the sorts of language communities that use this English idiom, and am not seeking to conduct a survey**, as per Stuart F's objection (though given my lack of explicit caveatation, I can see why he might object). Please, whatever you do, don't characterize your personal English Language and Usage.

Comment: Yes, sure, to catch somebody out. Perfectly good Americanese.

Comment: Not ever heard by me in California-land.

Comment: ....familiar to me, a native New Yorker expat who reads a lot of British authors.

Comment: It has a cricket feel to it, with a batsman caught before getting to the wicket. In America, one of the ways for a batter to get out is to have the batted ball caught. And base runners can be "caught out" when they get too far away from their safe bases ("taking a leadoff"), but there the _out_ means 'away from base' rather than "out" in the game sense. I believe there are probly more ways for sports analogs to work with this idiom.

Comment: I've never heard it in the US Midwest.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://www.chicagomag.com/chicago-magazine/felsenthal-files/may-2011/q-and-a-joseph-epstein/) from Chicago Magazine: "Their job is to catch out public figures at hypocrisy". Voting to close as this seems to be conducting a survey.

Comment: @StuartF I have amended my question to discourage people from responding as if this question were a survey. Also thanks for the link. Epstein is born-bred-and-educated here in Chicago, but I suspect as an almost-90 year old writer, his vocabulary may be poorly representative of typical native speakers around here. I can find printed material in Chinese from Chicago, but that fact would hardly typify native speakers in and around the City of Big Shoulders. :D The phrase still strikes me as British, and the sole response coming from the UK hardly discourages that impression.

Answer (score 4):

The transitive multi word verb **catch someone out** has several different senses:

> - *catch someone out* [show / discover wrongdoing] [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/catch-out) labels this sense 'mainly British'; M-W doesn't add these caveats]
>
> to show that someone is doing wrong[, expose a fault in someone]:
>
> *I suspected he wasn't telling me the truth, and one day I caught him out when I found some letters he'd written.*
>
> - *catch someone out* [trick; entrap] [[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/catch-out) labels this sense 'mainly British' and 'informal]']
>
> to trick someone into making a mistake [[AHD of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/catch+out) adds no caveat here]:
>
> *The examiner will try to catch you out, so stay calm and think carefully before you speak.*
>
> - *catch someone out* [cause difficulty] [M-W adds no caveat here either]
>
> to put someone in a difficult situation:
>
> *A lot of people were caught out by the sudden change in the weather.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary; amended slightly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catch-out)]

Perhaps Collins' 'mainly British' caveats are warranted, but the juries seem decidedly non-consensual. AHD and M-W tend to reflect US usage. As a Brit, I'm familiar with all the above senses, involving/not involving entrapment/a curve ball (ie intent to expose wrongdoing or lack of comprehension/proficiency); observer/examiner (assessor) involved or not.

Comment: I think our OP is suffering from _recency fallacy_. Aw shucks...I just caught him out. BTW +1

Comment: Thanks. My preference for the vernacular on the three would be "catch someone in the act", "trip them up", and maybe "catch them off guard" which isn't strictly synonymous with "causing difficulty". Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @JD Your Q was good, and was interesting to many users.